# Which protocol can be used for M2M communication in IoT?

Tags: microcontroller, wireless, m2m, iot

I am working on Contiki OS based platform development for IoT.I want to implement M2M in IoT.

Let say , i have one sensor and one switch.Now i want to trigger switch based on threshold of sensor readings.I can achieve this easily.But i want some solid M2M protocol , which can be easily used for binding multiple devices.IFTTT does the same thing from cloud.

So is their any proven protocol available for M2M in IoT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- service Discovery protocol : SSDP, mDNS/DNS-SD(Bonjour), Alljoyn, OMA
- Message protocol : MQTT(PUB&SUB system), CoAP(HTTP over UDP), Alljoyn, OMA
  -

Answer (score 2):

A protocol like [ModBus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modbus) sounds like it might be appropriate for your needs (obviously you would need to adapt it a little for the wireless comms space).

Comment: I think Modbus will not fit in 8/16  bit MCU. I want light weight M2M which can be used with PIC/STM32 MCUs.

Comment: Modbus is tiny, and easily implementable in an 8-bit machine.  However, it tends to be a master/slave relationship, which may not fit your needs...

Answer (score 1):

You can use [MQTT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MQTT) or [CoAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constrained_Application_Protocol) - both are proven standards with many lightweight implementations, even for 8-bit MCUs.

For more alternatives, see [my answer](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/14926/7953) to a similar question.